# Is it possible to use sbt testOnly with Slick TestKit?

Tags: scala, sbt, slick, slick-3.0, testkit

When I execute `sbt testOnly *JoinTest*` no tests are found and the following output is shown, but `com.typesafe.slick.testkit.tests.JoinTest` should have been executed:

```
testOnly *JoinTest*
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /ext/git/slick/slick-testkit/target/scala-2.10/test-classes...
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
[info] No tests to run for testkit/test:testOnly
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're so close. Try this instead:

```
testOnly -- *JoinTest*
```

The `--` allows you test send arguments to the test kit. Without that it's expecting a list of JUnit tests. More info [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html#options).

Comment: it gets better, not only can you run a single test, you can run that test against a single database as well: `test-only -- *MyTest*h2mem*` And if you want a debug dump then append: `-Dlog.qcomp.phases=debug -Dscala.slick.ansiDump=true`. Talk about an undocumented feature! After scouring the net finally found this gem from der Zeiger: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/818#issuecomment-44819119

Answer (score 0):

every time when I had a class called as yours `.JoinTest` to lunch / run all the tests from it I just wrote:

```
testOnly *.JoinTest
```

[link from sbt 0.13 with details about this](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Triggered-Execution.html)

additional if you want to run a specific test case from that class you can use the following command

```
testOnly *.JoinTest -- -z "test name you want to run"
```

to discover other commands that you can use with `--` you can take a look at this [link](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner)